# reading an xls in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am currently trying to read an xls file in pandas with multiple worksheets(each month has 1 worksheet per day). I don't need all worksheets just the sheets that are named 1 to 31 depending on which month. How would I go about just joining only those dataframes into 1 data frame.

I tried to hard-code the sheetnames in but got errors on days with only 28 or 30 days. 
Is there a way to just read the sheetname if it is an int as the sheets I dont need are usually named 'Sheet1' etc

Comment: you have an option of passing `sheetname` in `pd.read_excel`.

Comment: I know but some books have 28, 30 or 31 sheets I need plus a few I don't need. I'm just banging my head against a wall trying to figure out how I can just import the sheets I need

Comment: how do you know which month are you dealing with when reading your excel file?

Comment: The file name has the months name, I was hoping there would be a way to loop over the sheet names and just using the sheets which are or could be type int as the sheets not required will have letters in the sheetname